# `SIGSEGV` when reading `HW_CPU_CYCLES` on Alder Lake efficiency cores

Tags: linux, x86, performancecounter, perf, intel-pmu

I want to read the `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` + `PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES` on the Intel 12Gen.
This is my test program (based on `cpucycles/amd64rdpmc.c` from [SUPERCOP](https://bench.cr.yp.to/supercop.html)) :

```c
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct perf_event_attr attr;
static int fdperf = -1;
static struct perf_event_mmap_page *buf = 0;

long long cpucycles_amd64rdpmc(void) {
  long long result;
  unsigned int seq;
  long long index;
  long long offset;

  if (fdperf == -1) {
    attr.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
    attr.exclude_kernel = 1;
    fdperf = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    buf = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fdperf, 0);
  }

  do {
    seq = buf->lock;
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
    index = buf->index;
    offset = buf->offset;
    asm volatile("rdpmc;shlq $32,%%rdx;orq %%rdx,%%rax"
                 : "=a"(result)
                 : "c"(index - 1)
                 : "%rdx");
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
  } while (buf->lock != seq);

  result += offset;
  result &= 0xffffffffffff;
  return result;
}

int main() {

  long long c = cpucycles_amd64rdpmc();
  printf("counter: %llx\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

If I just run it, it sometimes `SIGSEGV`s out, some times it prints some counter value.

If I pin it to performance cores `taskset -c N ./a.out` with `N` being `1..15`, it always prints the counter,
If I pin it to efficiency cores, with `N` being `16..23` it always `SIGSEGV`s.
Hence, I assume that this MSR is not available on those cores.

1. Where can I find information which MSRs are available on which core?
2. Is there another PMC for cycles on the efficiency cores (except `rdtscp`)?
3. Edit: It `SIGSEGV`'s on the `rdpmc` instruction with `rcx=0x7ffff7ea9bd7`

Comment: The `perf` user-space tool often gets updated with names (and IDs) for uarch-specific events; you might find numbers there, or even be able to just use it to time programs with your code in a loop.  Interesting that the PMU is heterogeneous on Alder Lake.  It makes sense, but they went to some effort to make the instruction-set uniform across E and P cores.  (e.g. disabling AVX-512 on P cores, adding AVX2/FMA/BMI2 to their low-power uarch to use it as an E-core.)

Comment: hmm, thanks for that hint. I dug through the kernel code. I found, that the performance metrics seem to be enabled for the big `core`s https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4ea3c6425269d33da53c79d539ce9554117cf4d4/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L6296 and disabled for the small `atom`s https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4ea3c6425269d33da53c79d539ce9554117cf4d4/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L6317 So if I understood correctly, those counters cannot be read on the E-cores (but from a software side, not from a hardware side, right?)